# How to export csv file with SQL Developer with Pipe separator

Tags: oracle, pipe, sqlplus, export-to-csv, double-quotes

I need to export a file in CSV format with a pipe | delimiter instead of a comma and without "" (double quotes) for string field from Oracle SQL Developer. I must use SQLPLUS.
I try to execute (f5 button) with :

`set colsep |
spool C:\myFile.csv
select * from mytable;
spool off`

but it returns always commas separator and double quotes.

Comment: That looks like it should work; can you share (copy/paste) you command/output

Comment: with sqldeveloper or SQL*Plus - those are two different programs. in sql developer v4.2 you can do 
 set sqlformat delimited |
 spool ...
 select ...
 spool off

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thank you It runs. Can I remove double quotes for string fields with settings?

Comment: you can't remove string enclosures, but you can replace them, example set sqlformat delimited |  ' ' will give you single quotes vs double. if you use the GUI/grid export dialog, you can specify no quotes at all

Answer (score 0):

You can remove string enclosures in SQL Developer. There is a bug though. First overcome the bug:
1) Run a small statement like "select 1 abc from dual" (Ctrl+Enter).
2) Export it (right click on the results set) as delimited setting enclosures to "none" and separator to the charater of your choice.

Now type your query, starting with "set sqlformat delimited" (probably you want ot use spool as well) and run it as a script (F5).

It works :)

Hadrian